# How to parse the messages sent from IoT Client to the Aws Thing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

I am fairly new to the IoT. I have created a thing on Aws and I have created a client .Everything works fine when I test the set up. 
I am unable to parse the message sent from the client to the Aws IoT.

 Any Suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Rule` and use `SQL statements` to parse or filter messages sent by your `things`.

[image: Click here].

**For example:** You can insert those messages into `dynamodb` or `s3`, or call a lambda function to process further.

Check this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rules.html) for more information.